# Using Hexadecimals and Java Collection Framework Choices

Tags: java, collections, iterator, hex

I am using an input file that contains 20 hexadecimal values. I have to read the pairs and store them in an appropriate Java Collection, then sort the pairs in the increasing order of their hexadecimal values and use iterators to display the sorted pairs to the console. My question is which collection would be best to use? HashMap? LinkedList? Tree? etc. They all seem like good choices but I can't decide what would be more efficient.

```
#FF0000 //red
#000084 //blue
#00FF00 //green
#FFFF00 //yellow
#FF8C00 //Orange
#FFC0CB //Pink
#D3D3D3 //Grey
#964B00 //Brown
#800080 //Purple
#000000 //Black
#013220 //Dark green
#8B0000 //Dark Red
#00008B //Dark blue
#D97700 //Dark Orange
#363737 //Dark grey
#471E8A //Dark Purple
#7f7f00 //Dark yellow
#FFFFCC //Light Yellow
#C0D9D9 //Light Blue
#D8BFD8 //Light Purple
```

Comment: Are you sure about the [tag:css] tag? It seems like a mis-tag to me. And you would use the collection type that best suited the main purpose of your collection. If it will almost always be sorted, then maybe a TreeSet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a class to encapsulate the data, which will implement the Comparable interface

```
public class HexColor implements Comparable<HexColor>{
    private String hexCode;
    private String name;

    //Constructor, getters and setters
...
    public int compareTo(HexColor other){
        return this.hexCode.compareTo(other.hexCode);
    }
}
```

Then you can put it to a `List` and sort it via `Collections` class:

```
List<HexColor> colors = new ArrayList<HexColor>();
colors.add(new HexColor("#00xxxx", "color 1"));
colors.add(new HexColor("#00xxxx", "color 1"));
...
Collections.sort(colors);
//Some print in loop here
```

..you will be reading those from file

NOTE: Not tested. I assume sane values everywhere so there are no NP checks.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a list of pairs there. You could use a `Map` with the hex codes as keys and the names as values. The keys need to be sorted, so you'd need a `SortedMap` such as `TreeMap.` It could be a `TreeMap<Integer, String>` if you use `Integer.parseInt("xxxxxx", 16)` on the keys before insertion, which gives you better performance than leaving them as strings.

Comment: Why us a map to help?

Comment: I think NeplatnyUdaj's idea would seem more idiomatic to most folks. But for what it's worth, with `TreeMap` you could simply iterate over the pairs with something like this: `for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : colorsMap.entrySet()) { System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "->" + entry.getValue()); }`. And no explicit sorting call is needed.

Comment: can you be more specific about the map? like the difference from a hashmap and a treemap? @Lucas Ross

Comment: Good question--the most apparent difference is that TreeMap maintains a sorting of keys. That means no matter what order you insert the pairs in, TreeMap will sort the keys in their "natural ordering" (for integers, that's increasing order; for strings, it's lexicographical order) or by a Comparator that you give to it. HashMap doesn't guarantee an ordering.

Comment: so a Hashmap is like throwing stuff in the pile and a TreeMap is throwing stuff into the pile but in order. okay.